# change text of link onClick

Tags: jquery, text, hyperlink, onclick, alter

How do I toggle the text of this link

```html
<a class="btn btn-info" data-method="delete" href="javascript:void(0);" id="rearrange_button" rel="nofollow">Re-Arrange</a>
```

between 'Re-Arrange' and 'save' onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with using jQuery library.
This can be done with few lines of code.

Here below is a code.

### [live demo link](http://jsbin.com/ladapupane/1/edit?js,output)

```
$('#rearrange_button').on('click', function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  //console.log(text); 
  
  if (text == 'Re-Arrange') {
    $(this).text('Save');
  }
  else if(text == 'Save') {
    $(this).text('Re-Arrange');
  }
  
  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind actions on `.click` event of the required button.

```
$('.rearrange_button').click(function(){
    var $thisButton = $(this);
    $thisButton.toggleClass('Rearrange');
    if($thisButton.hasClass('Rearrange')){
        $thisButton.text('Save');         
    } else {
        $thisButton.text('Re-arrange');
    }
});
```